# knowrob_cad_parser in indigo

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am interested to use knowrob_gui package (catkin-based version in indigo) and it depends on the knowrob_cad_parser package.

Could you please let me know whether you implemented this parser package in indigo based on catkin ?

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207550/knowrob_cad_parser-in-indigo/) by [Robatics1](https://answers.ros.org/users/20457/robatics1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The package is available in the knowrob_addons repository:
https://github.com/knowrob/knowrob_addons/tree/indigo-devel/knowrob_cad_parser

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2015-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robatics1](https://answers.ros.org/users/20457/robatics1/) on 2015-04-22**:
In order to load some models through RoboEarth, do you have any instruction or materials indicating how to fill "Room Number", "Floor Number", "Street Number",  and "Street Name" ?

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2015-04-22**:
Please start a new question for new topics. Cf. RoboEarth: Please have a look at the **deprecated**  documentation [here])http://knowrob.org/doc/exchanging_information_via_roboearth). The servers seem to be down though, I don't have access and cannot promise anything regarding their uptime.

**Comment by [Robatics1](https://answers.ros.org/users/20457/robatics1/) on 2015-04-22**:
ok sure. Thanks.